# Get Type of ValidationAttribute causing a DbEntityValidationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I'm using the validation of the Entity Framework which relies on `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute`s. So when I call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` and an entity property fails validation, a `DbEntityValidationException` is thrown.

What I need to know is which `ValidationAttribute` exactly caused that validation error. **I.e. I need to know the `Type` of `ValidationAttribute` causing the `DbEntityValidationException` within my program.**

I already know how to iterate through the collections of validation errors inside the `DbEntityValidationException`. However the required information is not in there.

---

**Example**

Say I have this simple model with a single property which has two data annotations...

```
class Model
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    string Code { ... }
}
```

...and want to add a new instance of it like so:

```
try
{
    var model = new Model { Code = "ThisIsTooLong" };
    dbContext.Set<Model>().Add(model);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
{
    Type unsatisfiedValidationAttribute = MagicFunction();
}
```

In the above case an `DbEntityValidationException` is thrown and the variable `unsatisfiedValidationAttribute` should be equal to `typeof(MaxLengthAttribute)`.

What does `MagicFunction()` has to do to know whether the `Required` or the `MaxLength` annotation triggered the validation error?

Comment: The information you're after is simply not transferred to the validation errors. So: not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you looking for is [`Validator.TryValidateObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772(v=vs.110).aspx) static method:

```
var modelToSave = new Model { Code = "ThisIsTooLong" };
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool isValid=Validator.TryValidateObject( modelToSave, context, results, true);
```

In case your entity is not valid you are going to hold each failed validation in `results` list.

### Update

Well, a generic solution to get the `ValidationAttribute` using the `ErrorMessage` could be doing this:

```
public static ValidationAttribute GetAttribute(Type entityType, string property, string errorMessage)
{
   var attributes = typeof(entityType)
                   .GetProperty(property)
                   .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                   .OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
                   .ToArray();
   var attribute= attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ErrorMessage == errorMessage);
   return attribute;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not help. Your code does *not* determine whether it was the `Required` or the `MaxLength` annotations which caused the validation error.

Comment: But you could know that by `ErrorMessage` property in `ValidationResult` class. Also, you can personalize the `ErrorMessage` of your attributes to detect who is breaking your model. Usually what the people need to know is what is the property(ies) that is(are) causing the validation errors or the error messages.

Comment: You are right. Using the `ErrorMessage` to store the type name of an attribute seems to be the most cleanest solution. If you make a proper answer out of it, I will select it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you If you are using Entity Framework 4.1+. You can implement your own validation logic in your entity and return your own error codes for different validation issues.

> IValidatableObject is an interface that lives in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. While it is not part of the Entity Framework API, you can still leverage it for server-side validation in your Entity Framework classes. IValidatableObject provides a Validate method that Entity Framework will call during SaveChanges or you can call yourself any time you want to validate the classes.
>   Configurations such as Required and MaxLength perform validaton on a single field. In the Validate method you can have even more complex logic, for example, comparing two fields.

```
public class Blog : IValidatableObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string BloggerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (Title == BloggerName)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult
                 ("Blog Title cannot match Blogger Name", new[] { "Title", “BloggerName” });
            }
        }
    }
```

[Entity Framework Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx)

Comment: Using custom validations is not an option, because I need to know the attribute type for every failing data annotation not just for a few.